# Javascript - Reading Binary Records with FileReader into ArrayBuffers

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I have a binary data file where each `x` bytes is a record, and I have some format/mask (however you prefer to see it) to decipher that data. It's like, `short short int short float double`, blah blah. So I'm reading this file with the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), I'll need to be using [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)s eventually but I'm not there yet... So my question is two fold. Firstly, and most directly, **what is the best way to read in every `x` bytes from a binary file into an ArrayBuffer?**

Secondly, as I'm running into some problems... **why is the below script filling 5gb+ of RAM nearly immediately when reading a 500kb binary file?**

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(event) {

  // FileList object
  var files = event.target.files;
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // closures and magnets, how do they work
    reader.onload = (function(f) {
      return function(event) {

        // data file starts with header XML
        // indexOf +9 for </HEADER> and +1 for null byte
        var data_start = event.target.result.indexOf('</HEADER>')+10,

          // leverage jQuery for XML
          header = $(event.target.result.slice(0,data_start)),
          rec_len = parseInt(header.find('REC_LEN').text(),10);

        // var ArrayBuffer
        // define ArrayBufferView

        // loop through records
        for (var i = data_start; i<event.target.result.length; i+=rec_len) {

          // fill ArrayBuffer
          // add data to global data []
          console.log(i+' : '+event.target.result.slice(i, i+rec_len));
        }
      };
    })(f);

    // Read as Binary
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
  }
});
```

Comment: Might be logging or other artifact causing the memory bloat? ArrayBuffers should only take as much as memory you allocate?

Comment: The line `reader.onload = (function(f) { return function(event) {...` can be simplified to `reader.onload = function(event) {...`, btw.

Comment: have you looked at FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() ?

Comment: @thatjuan I have, and that's what I used in my solution!

Comment: @savinger maybe you should consider answering your own question for other people's benefit :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple general tips at least:

Using a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/DataView) is flexible but a bit slow -- it should be faster than `parseInt` called on strings but not as fast as array views. The upside is that it supports different byte orders, if your binary data requires. Use `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f)`, then in your `onload` callback, use something like

```
var dv = new DataView(arrayBuffer, [startCoord, [endCoord]]),
    result = [];
// in some loop for i...
    result[i] = [];
    result[i].push(dv.getInt8(coord));
    // coord += offset;
    result[i].push(dv.getFloat32(coord));
// end some loop
```

As I mentioned, faster would be to create multiple [views](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView) on on the ArrayBuffer, but you can't (to my knowledge) change the cursor position as you go -- so your mixed data types will be an issue.

To put the results into a typed array, just declare something like `var col1 = Uint8Array(length);`. The typed array subclasses are listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView#Typed_array_subclasses). Note that in my experience, typed arrays don't gain you much in terms of performance. Google around for some jsperf tests of typed arrays.